# React hooks - Dispatching a reset state from parent component

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-effect, use-reducer, use-ref

This is my application with the scenario reproduced, here the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-solomon-6e0sb) in codesandbox

I have two components, `Leagues` ( parent ) and `Details` ( Child ).

I have a implemented reset button example in the `Details` Component button which does

```
 const cleanArray = () => {
   setDataHomeTeam([]);
 };

<button onClick={cleanValue} type="button">Reset</button>
```

You can see in the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-solomon-6e0sb) that is emptying out an array of a team stat

**My question is, can i implement the same button but out from Details component and from the parent component `Leagues` for example? Whats the way to achieve it?**

I thought to go this way but i can not get it done.

So in my `Details.js`

```
let Details = forwardRef(({ ....

  const cleanArray = () => {
    setDataHomeTeam([]);
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
     return {
      cleanValue: cleanValue
     }
  });
```

in `App.js`

```
    <Leagues/>
    <button onClick={cleanValue} type="button">Reset</button>
    <Details ref={ref} />
```

I get this error : *'cleanValue' is not defined  no-undef*

is it something that i can not do with react? How can i achieve it?

Comment: tell me what you are trying to achieve. do you want to change the state of the child component from the parent or do you want to change  the state of parent from chiuld

Comment: Anytime i change the league, i want to empty the array i created from the last team selected, so i want to change the state of the child component from the parent in this case. Hope it is clear, thanks

Comment: first tell me  which is the parent and which is the child

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer, the parent is Leagues and the child is Details

Comment: let me rephrase. you have mentioned that you want to use useImperativeHandle. this is only used when you want to trigger a function in the child component from the parent component by adding a ref to the child. So what Im asking is what is the relationship between leagues and details component.

Comment: I need to understand which Hook i have to use to achieve that, the Leagues gets the leagues names, and the details component the team names of the leagues and the stats ( matches played for example )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach sounds correct except for lacking the way of calling the api `cleanValue` you exposed. Basically you have to call it via a `ref` you pass to it as following:

```js
function App() {
  const ref = useRef();

  return (
    <>
      <Leagues />
      {/* call it via ref */}
      <button onClick={() => ref.current.cleanValue()} type="button">Reset</button>
      <Details ref={ref} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-raman-c0zff?file=/src/components/Details.js

Comment: Thanks, i have tried but i still get the error TypeError
Cannot read property 'cleanValue' of null when i click on

Comment: It looks like you implemented the `<Details />` in a wrong way as both connecting with Redux + using fowardRef.  Check the sandbox where I fixed for you

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what you are trying to do, but here is a solution I think is going to work for your problem

let's say you wanna filter that array with the selected team which is **liverpool**, first if you have control over the incoming data I recommend changing the obj in the array likethis
`{day : 16 , teamName:"liverpool"}`, this is going to help you filter that array later,

then you `useEffect` & `useState` to update that array

```
 [teams, setTeams] = useState([]);
  // the array changes here {day: 1 , teamName : "sao paulo"} , {day:2 ,teamname:"liverpool"}] 

 useEffect(()=>{
 setTeams((T)=>{
   return T.filter((oneTeam)=>{
           return oneTeam.teamName == selectedTeam;
     });
})
},[teams,selectedTeam]);
```

Comment: Thanks, i want dynamically get rid of the last team selected columns when i change the league, so when i select Premier League, Sao Paulo columns have to removed for the Liverpool Columns

Comment: yea my code should work for your problem anything the selected team changes it will updated the whole `teams` array let me just make a minor update for you.

Comment: Thanks, i think i am asking something bit more complicated, if you want to show in my codesandbox, it is better